# how do I calculate the ismorphism group of a six-nodes-tree?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

How do I calculate the ismorphism group of a connected six-nodes-tree? The tree has a node centred and the other 5 nodes are leaves of the graph. I already know the answer is 6, which is the quotient between 720/120. But I do not know where 120 comes from.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood something: $6$ is a number, not a group. I’ve posted an ‘answer’ that may at least help you restate the question so that it makes sense, and we can proceed from there.

Comment: You might find [this question useful](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280801/symmetries-of-a-graph): it asks the same question about a slightly different graph.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your description correctly, you have the [star graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28graph_theory%29) $S_5$ with one central vertex and $5$ leaves radiating from it. Any automorphism of $S_5$ must send the central vertex to itself, because that’s the only vertex of degree $5$, and automorphims preserve vertex degrees. However, it can permute the other five vertices arbitrarily, so it is in fact $\operatorname{Sym}(5)$, the [symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) on $5$ objects. There are $5!=120$ permutations of $5$ objects, so the order of this group is $120$.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be seeking the number of labelled graphs isomorphic to the star graph $K_{1,5}$, i.e., the size of its *isomorphism class*.

[image: Star graph]

In general, the size of the isomorphism class a graph $G$ belongs to is given by $$\frac{|V(G)|!}{|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|},$$ where $V(G)$ is the set of vertices of the graph, and $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is the automorphism group of the graph.

For $K_{1,5}$, the automorphism group has size $5!=120$: we can permute the $5$ degree-one vertices arbitrarily and the degree-5 vertex must be fixed.  Hence the size of the isomorphism class is $$\frac{6!}{5!}=6.$$

The six labelled graphs in this isomorphism class are:

[image: The six graphs]

(Recall that two labelled graphs on the same vertex set are equal if they have the same edge set.)